# Get current value from Observable without subscribing (just want value one time)

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

How can I get the current value from an Observable without subscribing to it? I just want the current value one time and not new values as they are coming in.

Comment: you want to get data from `.map` directly while using http request ?

Comment: Actually no, I have my own made Observable (a state of the app), normally I use subscribe and act on changes as they are coming in, but now I need just to get the current state (without any updates of changes in the future)...

Comment: Does the take method work for you? 
http://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/take.md

Comment: Hmm, it looks like the take method returns an Observable, I just want the value (string in my case)...

Comment: You can check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387211/10974432

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need to use [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject),

> - BehaviorSubject is similar to ReplaySubject except it only remembers the last publication.
> - BehaviorSubject also requires you to provide it a default value of T. This means that all subscribers will receive a value immediately
>     (unless it is already completed).

It will give you the most recent value published by the Observable.

BehaviorSubject provides a `getter` property named `value` to get the most recent value passed through it.

---

[**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z1qq6a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

- In this example the value 'a' is written to the console:

```ts
//Declare a Subject, you'll need to provide a default value.
const subject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject("a");
```

USAGE:

```ts
console.log(subject.value); // will print the current value
```

---

### Conceal the Subject and only expose it's value

In case you want to conceal your BehaviorSubject and only expose it's value, let's say from a Service, you can use a getter like this.

```ts
export class YourService {
  private subject = new BehaviorSubject('random');

  public get subjectValue() {
    return this.subject.value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a state like this (with TypeScript): `myState:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();`, so I must use BehaviorSubject instead of EventEmitter, right? Something like `myState:BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('default state');`

Comment: yes, that's right. EventEmitter uses simple Observable.

Comment: But BehaviorSubject has the 'next' method, so if a class exposes a BehaviorSubject to its clients then those clients have the ability to trigger 'next' and update the variable. What is needed is a way to expose just the value and Observable members of a BehaviorSubject in a source object to its clients. Does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: @Neutrino: with TypeScript you could cast the `BehaviorSubject<T>` into `Observable<T>` and only expose that observable to others. Would it be fine with you?

Comment: I'm not sure that really achieves much. All anyone has to do is assign the cast object to an untyped variable and they can still call 'next' on it can't they?

Answer (score 123):

**Quick answer:**

> ...I just want the current value one time and not new values as they are coming in...

You will still use `subscribe`, but with `pipe(take(1))` so it gives you one single value.

eg. `myObs$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(value => alert(value));`

Also see: Comparison between [`first()`, `take(1)` or `single()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345969/angular-2-using-rxjs-take1-vs-first)

---

**Longer answer:**

#### The general rule is you should only ever get a value out of an observable with `subscribe()`

*(or async pipe if using Angular)*

`BehaviorSubject` definitely has its place, and when I started with RxJS I used to often do `bs.value()` to get a value out. As your RxJS streams propagate throughout your whole application (and that's what you want!) then it will become harder and harder to do this. Often you'll actually see `.asObservable()` used to 'hide' the underlying type to *prevent* someone from using `.value()` - and at first this will seem mean, but you'll start to appreciate why it's done over time. In addition you'll sooner or later need a value of something that *isn't* a `BehaviorSubject` and there won't be a way to make it so.

Back to the original question though. Especially if you don't want to 'cheat' by using a `BehaviorSubject`.

The better approach is always to use `subscribe` to get a value out.

`obs$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(value => { ....... })`

OR

`obs$.pipe(first()).subscribe(value => { ....... })`

The difference between these two being `first()` will error **if the stream has already completed** and `take(1)` will not emit any observables if the stream has completed or doesn't have a value immediately available.

Note: This is considered better practice even if you are are using a BehaviorSubject.

However, if you try the above code the observable's 'value' will be 'stuck' inside the subscribe function's closure and you may well need it in the current scope. One way around this if you really have to is this:

```js
const obsValue = undefined;
const sub = obs$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(value => obsValue = value);
sub.unsubscribe();

// we will only have a value here if it was IMMEDIATELY available
alert(obsValue);
```

Important to note that the subscribe call above doesn't *wait* for a value. If nothing is available right away then the subscribe function won't ever get called, and I put the unsubscribe call there deliberately to prevent it 'appearing later'.

So not only does this look remarkably clumsy - it won't work for something that isn't immediately available, like a result value from an http call, but it would in fact work with a behavior subject (or more importantly something that is *upstream and known to be a BehaviorSubject**, or a `combineLatest` that takes two `BehaviorSubject` values). And definitely don't go doing `(obs$ as BehaviorSubject)`- ugh!

This previous example is still considered a bad practice in general - it's a mess. I only do the previous code style if I want to see if a value is available immediately and be able to detect if it isn't.

#### Best approach

You're far better off if you can to keep everything as an observable as long as possible - and only subscribe when you absolutely need the value - and not try to 'extract' a value into a containing scope which is what I'm doing above.

eg. Lets' say we want to make a report of our animals, if your zoo is open. You might think you want the 'extracted' value of `zooOpen$` like this:

#### Bad way

```js
zooOpen$: Observable<boolean> = of(true);    // is the zoo open today?
bear$: Observable<string> = of('Beary');
lion$: Observable<string> = of('Liony');

runZooReport() {

   // we want to know if zoo is open!
   // this uses the approach described above

   const zooOpen: boolean = undefined;
   const sub = this.zooOpen$.subscribe(open => zooOpen = open);
   sub.unsubscribe();

   // 'zooOpen' is just a regular boolean now
   if (zooOpen) 
   {
      // now take the animals, combine them and subscribe to it
      combineLatest(this.bear$, this.lion$).subscribe(([bear, lion]) => {

          alert('Welcome to the zoo! Today we have a bear called ' + bear + ' and a lion called ' + lion); 
      });
   }
   else 
   {
      alert('Sorry zoo is closed today!');
   }
}
```

#### So why is this SO BAD

- What if `zooOpen$` comes from a webservice? How will the previous example ever work? It actually wouldn't matter how fast your server is - you'd never get a value with the above code if `zooOpen$` was an http observable!
- What if you want to use this report 'outside' this function. You've now locked away the `alert` into this method. If you have to use the report elsewhere you'd have to duplicate this!

#### Good way

Instead of trying to access the value in your function, **consider instead a function that creates a new Observable and doesn't even subscribe to it!**

It instead returns a new observable that can be consumed 'outside'.

By keeping everything as observables and using `switchMap` to make decisions you can create new observables that can themselves be the source of other observables.

```js
getZooReport() {

  return this.zooOpen$.pipe(switchMap(zooOpen => {

     if (zooOpen) {

         return combineLatest(this.bear$, this.lion$).pipe(map(([bear, lion] => {

                 // this is inside 'map' so return a regular string
                 return "Welcome to the zoo! Today we have a bear called ' + bear + ' and a lion called ' + lion";
              }
          );
      }
      else {

         // this is inside 'switchMap' so *must* return an observable
         return of('Sorry the zoo is closed today!');
      }

   });
 }
```

The above **creates a new observable** so we can run it elsewhere, and pipe it more if we wish.

```js
 const zooReport$ = this.getZooReport();
 zooReport$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(report => {
    alert('Todays report: ' + report);
 });

 // or take it and put it into a new pipe
 const zooReportUpperCase$ = zooReport$.pipe(map(report => report.toUpperCase()));
```

Note the following:

- I don't subscribe until I absolutely need to - in this case that's outside the function
- The 'driving' observable is `zooOpen$` and that uses `switchMap` to 'switch' to a different observable which is ultimately the one returned from `getZooReport()`.
- The way this works if `zooOpen$` ever changes then it cancels everything and starts again inside the first `switchMap`. Read up about `switchMap` for more about that.
- Note: The code inside `switchMap` must return a new observable. You can make one quickly with `of('hello')` - or return another observable such as `combineLatest`.
- Likewise: `map` must just returns a regular string.

As soon I started making a mental note not to subscribe until I *had* to I suddenly started writing much more productive, flexible, cleaner and maintainable code.

Another final note: If you use this approach with Angular you could have the above zoo report without a single `subscribe` by using the `| async` pipe. This is a great example of the 'don't subscribe until you HAVE to' principal in practice.

```js
// in your angular .ts file for a component
const zooReport$ = this.getZooReport();
```

and in your template:

```js
<pre> {{ zooReport$ | async }} </pre>
```

See also my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54209999/16940

Also not mentioned above to avoid confusion:

- [`tap()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) may be useful sometimes to 'get the value out of an observable'. If you aren't familiar with that operator read into it. RxJS uses 'pipes' and a `tap()` operator is a way to 'tap into the pipe' to see what's there.

---

#### With .toPromise() / async

See 'Use toPromise() with async/await to emit the last Observable value as a Promise' in https://benlesh.medium.com/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875

---

#### With Angular signals! (Angular 16+)

Angular 16 introduced a preview of a new Signals feature. While not feature complete you can already start use signals in your components. One of the design goals is precisely to fix this 'pain point'.

With `customer = toSignal(customer$, { requireSync: true })` you can create a signal that updates when the observable value changes and access the 'immediate' value with `customer()` without the normal boilerplate described above. Angular automatically handles the unsubscription to the observable that is created in order to achieve this.

Thoughts on this:

- Accessing a signal with `()` to get its value is **always** synchronous and so if your observable doesn't have a value you'll run into some of the same problems described above. That's what `{ requireSync: true }` is for (check API docs for more info - subject to change).
- I'm not suggesting creating a new signal at time of needing the value of an existing observable. That's sort of pointless! This approach is only going to be useful if you're updating your component to use signals either in part or fully.
- Signal APIs are not final so check for blogs for the latest information.

Comment: This is amazingly clear and the best answer to this problem that I've seen. Kudos for this and thank you !

Comment: @Shem ha thanks. I did get a little carried away with this answer!

Comment: Is it still necessary to unsubscribe in this case?

Comment: @tobias if you're getting the value immediately and using `take(1)` then unsubscribing wouldn't ever be needed. But generally this approach should be avoided - unless you know 100% that a value is immediately available.

Comment: I don't have time to update the question right now but you can also use `await` in asynchronous functions. https://indepth.dev/rxjs-for-await-what/

Comment: The other way to think is that Bad way is hard to do unit test and Good way is easy to do unit test.

Comment: Edit: Added info about Angular Signals

Comment: why not just use behaviouralSubject.value ? I don't need its reactivity and just need the current value when component loads (for 1 particular scenario alone). Of course I need subscription in other places so I have to use behavioural subject only.

Comment: @Ganesh that's a perfect example of when the new signals might be a good fit. When I started with Angular I ended up with many occurrences of `bs$.value` in my code. I always ended up getting in a mess in the end. At the simplest level your code might work with a behavior subject today but then tomorrow you need to combine it with some other input or data and then suddenly you can't use `.value` anymore. It works, but feels clumsy and I never use it anymore.

Answer (score 11):

```
const value = await this.observableMethod().toPromise();
```

Comment: This is actually the method that works for me.

Comment: This is a good article about promises + RxJS: https://benlesh.medium.com/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875 - see the section `Use toPromise() with async/await to emit the last Observable value as a Promise`

Answer (score 2):

As ToPromise() is deprecated from some time here is the new rxjs way to do this:

```
let value = await lastValueFrom(someObservable);
```

or

```
let value = await firstValueFrom(someObservable);
```

If you are not sure that something is inside already you can use:

```
let value = await lastValueFrom(someObservable, {defaultValue: "some value"})
```

https://indepth.dev/posts/1287/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. Probably write that behaviorsubject in a service. Declare it as a private and expose only the value that you have set. Something like this

```
 @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
 })
  export class ConfigService {
    constructor(private bname:BehaviorSubject<String>){
       this.bname = new BehaviorSubject<String>("currentvalue");
    }

    getAsObservable(){
       this.bname.asObservable();
    }
 }
```

This way the external users only have access to subscribe to the behaviorSubject and you get to set the desired value in the service.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Observable constructor to create an observable stream of any type. The constructor takes as its argument the subscriber function to run when the observable’s subscribe() method executes. A subscriber function receives an Observer object, and can publish values to the observer's next() method.Try this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'async-observable-pipe',
  template: '<div><code>observable|async</code>: Time: {{ time | async }} . 
</div>'
})
export class AsyncObservablePipeComponent {
  time = new Observable<string>((observer: Observer<string>) => {
    setInterval(() => observer.next(new Date().toString()), 1000);
  });
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: is there any thing else you want ? @adiga