# How to merge multiple Observable responses

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

I'm trying to merge multiple responses from Observables to one stream. I'm fetching `companies` and each company has multiple `inspections` (which are stored as IDs). For each `inspection` I have to fetch the respective data.

This is how my code currently looks like. Please check the commented out section for the current result.

```
// Get companies
getCompanies().pipe(
   switchMap(companies => companies.map(
     company => {
       return company['inspections'].map(inspection => {
         // Get inspections by each company
         return this.getInspectionById(inspection['id']);
       })
     }
   ))
).subscribe(result => {
   /* 
     console.log(result) returns the following (company1 has two inspections, company2 has three 
     inspections):

     (2) [Observable, Observable]
       0: Observable
       1: Observable

     (3) [Observable, Observable, Observable]
       0: Observable
       1: Observable
       2: Observable
   */
});
```

As you can see, my subscription currently returns the Observables only. I guess I'm just missing the part for merging the data streams, I've tried different operators like mergeMap, combineLatest, forkJoin etc. but didn't found the right one.

My desired output would be something like this (quite the same as above, but real data instead of observables):

```
company1:
   company_data: ...
   inspections: [a, b]

company2:
   company_data: ...
   inspections: [a, b, c]
```

Does anybody know which operator to use and how to do it?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably looking for `forkJoin` operator for this case, something like below

```
getCompanies().pipe(
  switchMap(companies => forkJoin(
     companies.map(company => forkJoin(
       company['inspections'].map(inspection =>
         this.getInspectionById(inspection['id'])
       )
     ).pipe(
         map(inspections => ({...company, inspections }))
       )
     )
   ))
)
```

`forkJoin` will combine the observable array and return a single Observable

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much! When trying to solve it I tried forkJoin as well but missed the first forkJoin.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right I think you are confused in your approach. As far as I understood you have observables inside your observable. You subscribe your wrapper observable and get correctly the inner observables. Now you need the value of those. For that this might be helpful: [Get current value from Observable without subscribing (just want value one time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339016/get-current-value-from-observable-without-subscribing-just-want-value-one-time).