# How to use valueChanges to only read data once in firebase database?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

My ionic 5 (Angular) project uses Google firebase database.

This is an example code I used to read data from firebase database. I just want to read the data only once. As `valueChanges()` is a observable, I guess I have to unsubscribe the subscription every time when use it.

```
constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.tempsub = db.list('items').valueChanges().subscribe(data=>{...});
    this.tempsub.unsubscribe()
  }
```

Do I have to unsubscribe it in my use case? Is there a better solution to read the data from firebase database only once?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339016/get-current-value-from-observable-without-subscribing-just-want-value-one-time/37344187?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `take` operator to configure the desired number of emissions.
Using `take(1)` will emit the first value, then complete and unsubscribe.

```ts
db.list('items').valueChanges()
  .pipe(take(1))
  .subscribe(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `forEach()` which returns a promise that will either resolve or reject when the Observable completes or errors.

You cannot unsubscribe from `forEach()`, but you don't need to unsubscribe in this case since `take(1)` takes the first value from the source, then completes.

```
db.list('items').valueChanges()
  .pipe(take(1))
  .forEach(items => do something with items);
```