# Trigger method based on the value of Observable

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to perform something this based on the value of an Observable:

```js
myObservable$ = of(1, 2, 3)

if(myObservable$ >= 2 ){
doSomething();
} else {
doSomethingElse();
}
```

I would like to avoid subscribing to it as I keep hearing it's a bad practice. What would you recommend?

I have tried using the tap() operator but it never seems to work. When I debug,  I realise that the methods called by the tap operator are never called.

Comment: I think avoiding subscribing to observables might be a misunderstanding as that is one of their key features.  Their whole premise is "values over time".  Can you cite where you saw that and maybe we can re-contextualize it?

Comment: Sure, from what I understand, avoiding subscribing to observables can also avoid leaks as one can forget to unsubscribe. Also, "getting out of" the observable to assign values to class attributes for example can be tricky, especially in big applications. I am not sure if that would apply to my case though, I am new to using observables so I am not sure what to decide

Comment: Here's a link where they also explain why observables should be kept as observables for as long as possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339016/get-current-value-from-observable-without-subscribing-just-want-value-one-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
myObservable$.pipe(
  tap(value => {
    if (value >= 2) {
      doSomething();
    } else {
      doSomethingElse();
    }
  })
).subscribe();
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to subscribe to the observable for tap() to get activated?

Comment: Yes, it works like that

Comment: If it worked for you, try to upvote and mark as accepted so other people can see the answer more easily. Glad to help :)