# How to return value from function which has Observable subscription inside?

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I dont know how to extract value from Observable to be returned by function in which Observable is present. I need just a value from it to be returned, nothing else.

Current version which works

```
function getValueFromObservable() {
    this.store.subscribe(
        (data:any) => {
            console.log(data)
        }
    )
}
getValueFromObservable()
```

I need this to work, function to return value, and then:

```
function getValueFromObservable() {
    this.store.subscribe(
        (data:any) => {
            return data
        }
    )
}
console.log(getValueFromObservable())
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should return an Observable/Promise and pass the data via it when your observable is resolved

Comment: Can you put some simple code for this?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is an anti-pattern: You're trying to "synchronize" an async task. That's not the way observables are supposed to work. In short, in most cases, a function having an observable as the input should also return an observable - or return nothing. And when you need to do something with the output, subscribe to it. In this case if you want to console.log the data, just do it inside `subscribe`

Comment: I understand all you said. I am just using console log as demo, I will use that data further, thats why I need it to console log outside the observable. The point is to have the function which when you can subscribes the observable, get data, unsubscribe and return data in that function so I can use that data further. I know it is anti-pattern, but I need it to work. Any help is appreciated. Current my solution works, but I am not confident too much about it.

Comment: Attention please!
Code from section 'SOLUTION' is absolutely incorrect. Don't use it!
It will work only if section

    this.store.subscribe(
        (data:any) => {
            output = data
        }
    ).unsubscribe()

will be finished until return. Otherwise it will return undefined.

Comment: I am coming with Java background, this async stuff is killing me. For example I am expecting to return a value from a function but it never returns. Do you recommend any source about Javascript Async issue.

Comment: try with "of" from import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

Answer (score 89):

EDIT: updated code in order to reflect changes made to the way pipes work in more recent versions of RXJS. All operators (take in my example) are now wrapped into the pipe() operator.

I realize that this Question was quite a while ago and you surely have a proper solution by now, but for anyone looking for this I would suggest solving it with a Promise to keep the async pattern.

A more verbose version would be creating a new Promise:

```
function getValueFromObservable() {
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
        this.store.pipe(
           take(1) //useful if you need the data once and don't want to manually cancel the subscription again
         )
         .subscribe(
            (data:any) => {
                console.log(data);
                resolve(data);
         })
    })
}
```

On the receiving end you will then have "wait" for the promise to resolve with something like this:

```
getValueFromObservable()
   .then((data:any)=>{
   //... continue with anything depending on "data" after the Promise has resolved
})
```

A slimmer solution would be using RxJS' .toPromise() instead:

```
function getValueFromObservable() {
    return this.store.pipe(take(1))
       .toPromise()   
}
```

The receiving side stays the same as above of course.

Comment: What is the return type of your `getValueFromObservable` function?

Comment: Should be a promise with whatever type the store data is. e.g. Promise<StoreType>

Comment: It's an interesting approach: use backward-compatibility feature to make the code compatible with your current knowledge, even for new code.  I think he probably learned Observable usage since this post which would be preferable.

Comment: you're still returning a promise that needs to be resolved and not returning a value directly.

Comment: Property 'take' does not exist on type 'Observable<>'

Comment: @Roj I am sorry for the very late reply. Yes it is still returning a Promise. It simply is not possible to return a value directly (synchronously) if the value is retrieved asynchronously.

Comment: @Memmo try .pipe(take(1)) instead

Comment: This answer is so confusing.  The question was about Observable and the answer  is using a Promise??

Comment: @Rogelio the process runs asynchronously so there will always be a promise involved. If you wanted, you could add an await within the function, so it would resolve the object there, and then return the object. Due to it running asynchronously, the return type will still be a Promise<data type>, though. This would allow you to do other manipulations on the object within that function.

Answer (score 28):

This is not exactly correct idea of using `Observable`

In the component you have to declare class member which will hold an object (something you are going to use in your component)

```
export class MyComponent {
  name: string = "";
}
```

Then a `Service` will be returning you an `Observable`:

```
getValueFromObservable():Observable<string> {
    return this.store.map(res => res.json());
}
```

`Component` should prepare itself to be able to retrieve a value from it:

```
OnInit(){
  this.yourServiceName.getValueFromObservable()
    .subscribe(res => this.name = res.name)
}
```

You have to assign a value from an `Observable` to a variable:

And your template will be consuming variable `name`:

```
<div> {{ name }} </div>
```

Another way of using `Observable` is through `async` pipe http://briantroncone.com/?p=623

**Note**: If it's not what you are asking, please update your question with more details

Comment: Well not quite. The problem is that data is captured inside the observable and I can just console log it. I want to return that value and console.log or whatever from different file by calling the function in which it resides.

Comment: Andrei pointed out how to make the `name` available outside the callback by assigning it to the component's `name` variable. It is not possible to return `name` synchronously in your case.

Comment: @Matt: I can't use it in `Oninit` like that, What if I need to return explicitly, My calling code looks like this  `this.actions$.ofType(SearchActions.SEARCH_MULTIPLE_NEW_QUERY).map(toPayload).fnWithMultipleAsyncReturns()`

Comment: @ishandutta2007 Hey there. You better create a new question on SO regarding your issue.

Comment: @Matt: created, in case you want to take a look (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43381922/return-subject-from-inside-map)

Comment: Is `this.name` can be accessible in any other function of this component,  if I declared on top of this component as `name : any `?

Comment: @Sohail, yes, it will be accessible everywhere inside the component `MyComponent`, type doesn't matter.

Comment: Here is a better link for using async Observable pipes than that blog: https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Answer (score 7):

If you want to pre-subscribe to the same Observable which will be returned, just use

> .do():

```
function getValueFromObservable() {
    return this.store.do(
        (data:any) => {
            console.log("Line 1: " +data);
        }
    );
}

getValueFromObservable().subscribe(
        (data:any) => {
            console.log("Line 2: " +data)
        }
    );
```

Comment: You can also use other operators like `.map(data => data)` which does the same thing and then subscribe it wherever you expect the result

Comment: I agree with ashok_khuman. Here is the guide https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: This could be a good answer, but in fact that you did not explain anything about it, makes it to a bad answer. What does "pre-subscribe" mean? And should it solve the question from thread opener?

Comment: note that in RxJS 6 `do` is now called `tap` and you must use it in a pipe. Also note that `tap` takes multiple parameters for different handlers such as `next`, `complete` and `error`.

Answer (score 7):

> The problem is that data is captured inside the observable and I can just console log it. I want to return that value and console.log or whatever from different file by calling the function in which it resides.

Looks like you are looking for a "current value" getter inside an observable, when it emits and after an emission.

`Subject` and `Observable` doesn't have such a thing. When a value is emitted, it is passed to its subscribers and the `Observable` is done with it.

You may use `BehaviorSubject` which stores the last emitted value and emits it immediately to new subscribers.

It also has a `getValue()` method to get the current value;

Further Reading:

[RxJS BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject)

[How to get current value of RxJS Subject or Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089977/how-to-get-current-value-of-rxjs-subject-or-observable)

Answer (score 3):

Observable values can be retrieved from any locations. The source sequence is first *pushed* onto a special *observer* that is able to emit elsewhere. This is achieved with the **Subject class** from the Reactive Extensions (RxJS).

```
var subject = new Rx.AsyncSubject();  // store-last-value method
```

Store value onto the *observer*.

```
subject.next(value); // store value
subject.complete(); // publish only when sequence is completed
```

To retrieve the value from elsewhere, subscribe to the observer like so:

```
subject.subscribe({
  next: (response) => {
      //do stuff. The property name "response" references the value
  }
});
```

Subjects are both Observables and Observers. There are other [Subject types](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/subjects.html#different-types-of-subjects) such as BehaviourSubject and ReplaySubject for other usage scenarios.

Don't forget to import RxJS.

```
var Rx = require('rxjs');
```

Answer (score 3):

While the previous answers may work in a fashion, I think that using BehaviorSubject is the correct way if you want to continue using observables.

Example:

```
    this.store.subscribe(
        (data:any) => {
            myService.myBehaviorSubject.next(data)
        }
    )
```

In the Service:

```
let myBehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubjet(value);
```

In component.ts:

```
this.myService.myBehaviorSubject.subscribe(data => this.myData = data)
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The decent way would be to return the observable from a function and subscribe to it wherever required, because observables are lazy, they will start emitting values only when they are subscribed.

Here I have one more interesting event driven solution, which I initially used to play around with. Following example does this by using "**events**" module of nodejs. **You can use it with other frameworks where similar module exists**(**Note**: Syntax and style might change depending on module used).

```
var from =require("rxjs").from;
var map = require("rxjs/operators").map;
var EventEmitter = require("events");

function process(event) {
    from([1,2,3]).pipe(
        map(val => `The number is:: ${val}`)
    ).subscribe((data) => {
       event.emit("Event1", data); //emit value received in subscribe to the "Event1" listener
    });
}

function main() {
   class Emitter extends EventEmitter{};
    var event = new Emitter(); //creating an event
    event.on("Event1", (data)=>{ //listening to the event of name "Event1" and callback to log returned result
        console.log(data); //here log, print, play with the data you receive
    });
    process(event); //pass the event to the function which returns observable.
}

main(); //invoke main function
```

It is just an example to showcase an idea where we can pass data from different places by method of emitting and listening. This is also known as event-driven code.

Comment: This worked for me, not using node, but using `map` within the `pipe` to log the value. Then the `Observable` can be subscribed to upstream.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to check if the data was stored on the client, or if I had to get it from the server via API call. Then returning a new observer and subscribing to this did the trick. The first time the data is fetched from the server and after is return the this.allUsers, since I set this data after the API was called and data was returned.

```
    private _allUsers: EnconUser[] = undefined;
    get allUsers(): EnconUser[]
    {
      return this._allUsers;
    }
    set allUsers(value: EnconUser[])
    {
      this.storage.store('allUsers', value);
      this._allUsers = value;
    }

    public getAllUsers() : Observable<EnconUser[]>
    {
      if (this.allUsers == undefined)
      {
        return new Observable((obs) => {this.httpClient.get<EnconUser[]>(`http://api/getallusers`).subscribe(data=>{this.allUsers=data; obs.next(data); })});
      }
      else
      {
       return new Observable((obs) => {
        obs.next(this.allUsers);
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For example this is my html template:

```
<select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="genre" name="genre"
                  [(ngModel)]="film.genre"
                  #genreInput="ngModel"
                  required>
            <option value="">Choose...</option>
            <option *ngFor="let genre of genres;" [value]="genre.value">{{genre.name}}</option>
          </select>
```

This is the field that binded with template from my Component:

```
  // Genres of films like action or drama that will populate dropdown list.
  genres: Genre[];
```

I fetch genres of films from server dynamically. In order do communicate with server I have created `FilmService`

This is the method which communicate server:

```
 fetchGenres(): Observable<Genre[]> {
    return this.client.get(WebUtils.RESOURCE_HOST_API + 'film' + '/genre') as Observable<Genre[]>;
  }
```

Why this method returns `Observable<Genre[]>` not something like `Genre[]`?

JavaScript is `async` and it does not wait for a method to return value after an expensive process. With expensive I mean a process that take a time to return value. Like fetching data from server. So you **have to** return reference of Observable and subscribe it.

For example in my Component :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.filmService.fetchGenres().subscribe(
      val => this.genres = val
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the single-threaded,asynchronous,promise-oriented,reactive-trending world of javascript `async/await` is the imperative-style programmer's best friend:

```
(async()=>{

    const store = of("someValue");
    function getValueFromObservable () {
        return store.toPromise();
    }
    console.log(await getValueFromObservable())

})();
```

And in case `store` is a sequence of multiple values:

```
  const aiFrom = require('ix/asynciterable').from;
  (async function() {

     const store = from(["someValue","someOtherValue"]);
     function getValuesFromObservable () {
        return aiFrom(store);
     }
     for await (let num of getValuesFromObservable()) {
       console.log(num);
     }
  })();
```

Comment: Why would I use asynchronousness in case of a data array?

Comment: @JanosVinceller This is just an example, for focusing on other parts of the code. You can replace `from(["someValue","someOtherValue"])` with an observable of your choice that emits more than one value. I guess, it might be more suitable to have used `interval(1000)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getValueFromObservable() {
    this.store.subscribe(
        (data:any) => {
            return data
        }
    )
}
console.log(getValueFromObservable())
```

In above case console.log runs before the promise is resolved so no value is displayed, change it to following

```
function getValueFromObservable() {
    return this.store
}

getValueFromObservable()
 .subscribe((data: any) => {
    // do something here with data
    console.log(data);
});
```

other solution is when you need data inside getValueFromObservable to return the observable using of operator and subscribe to the function.

```
 function getValueFromObservable() {
        return this.store.subscribe((data: any) => {
            // do something with data here
            console.log(data);
            //return again observable.
            return of(data);
       })
    }

    getValueFromObservable()
     .subscribe((data: any) => {
        // do something here with data
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning an observable from a function.

**rxjsFunction.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

export function getValueFromObservable() {

    return new Observable( (obs) => {
        obs.next(5);
    })
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import { getValueFromObservable } from "./rxjsFunction";

getValueFromObservable().subscribe((value) => {
    next: console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, and also a "wrong" approach, but I will share my solution, I had a similar problem, because I had a service returning a Subscription instead of an Observable

The solution would be to pass a callback function to the function that returns a Subscription, and it can be called once the value was updated.

Those two first solutions are going to be called whenever there is an update to the Subscription.

```js
function getValueFromObservable(callback: Function) {
  return this.store.subscribe(
    (data:any) => callback(data)
  )
}

getValueFromObservable((data) => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

BUT as already stated in other answers, the best way to deal with it would be to return an Observable:

```js
function getValueFromObservable() {
  return this.store; // Now this actually returns an Observable and not a Subscription
}
    
getValueFromObservable().subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Now, if you want to manually get the last value from the Subscription, I would recommend using lastValueFrom https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/lastValueFrom

```js
import { interval, take, lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

function execute() {
  return interval(200).pipe(take(10)); // creates interval Observable of 200ms
}

execute().subscribe((data) => console.log(data));

lastValueFrom(execute()).then((data) => {
  console.log(`The last values was ${data}`);
});
```