# Bind a Promise return inside a get function

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2

Hello im new in typeScript and Angular.
I need to get a value in storage, the storage.get return a promise, so i try:

```
getNomeUsuario():string{
    var that = this;
    this.storage.get('nomeUsuario').then(function(nome){
        that.nomeUsuario = nome;
    }.bind(this));
    return this.nomeUsuario;
}
```

The problem is that always return a undefined.
I also get the same with an arrow function.

```
getNomeUsuario():string{
    this.storage.get('nomeUsuario').then((nome)=>{
        this.nomeUsuario = nome;
    });
    return this.nomeUsuario;
}
```

How can I return the nome value ?

Sorry about my English hehe

Comment: It's because `getNomeUsuario()` almost instantly returns the current value of `this.nomeUsuario`, before asynchronous `this.storage.get()` changes the `this.nomeUsuario` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `this.storage.get("nomeUsuario")` is asynchronous, there's no way the `getNomeUsuario()` method can return it's value without returning a Promise, so you'll need to do it like this:

```
getNomeUsuario(): Promise<string> {
  return this.storage.get("nomeUsuario");   
}
```

And handle the Promise where you call `getNomeUsuario()`.

ps: you could also use an Observable, but it would add complexity without any benefits.

Answer (score 0):

`this.storage.get('nomeUsuario')` executes asynchronously, and when you returns `that.nomeUsuario`, the promise wasn't executed yet and `that.nomeUsuario` still undefined. Try to insert this `return` into `.then` section like this:

```
getNomeUsuario():string{
    var that = this;
    this.storage.get('nomeUsuario').then((nome)=>{
        that.nomeUsuario = nome;
        return that.nomeUsuario;
    });
}
```

Comment: when i try return inside promise i get a compilation error, getNomeUsuario need to return a string;

Comment: if i change return to any getNomeUsuario():any its compile but the value return is undefined.

Comment: Hm, try to return `this.storage.get(...` too, like this: `return this.storage.get(...`

Comment: i get a promisse<string> return not a string.

Comment: @RodrigoSene, yes, it was a bad idea. Try to `console.log(that.nomeUsuario)`  after `that.nomeUsuario = nome;` row. what's the result?

Comment: this.storage.get('nomeUsuario').then((nome)=>{
            that.nomeUsuario = nome;
            console.log(that.nomeUsuario);
            return that.nomeUsuario;
        });                                                                                                                      whit this i get the name...                                                                                   console.log(JSON.stringify(this.dadosBaseProvider.getNomeUsuario())); with this i get undefined

Comment: @RodrigoSene, and what do you get in console, when you are trying to `console.log(that.nomeUsuario);`?

Comment: the name; 
2VM11199 main.js:1139  Rodrigo Sene

Comment: @RodrigoSene, is it an expected result? what it should be?

Comment: yes, inside the arrow function the result is exactly the expected.

Comment: @RodrigoSene, sorry, but it looks like i don't have enough knowledge to advice something else =(

Comment: thanks for help... i solve this with [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291783/how-to-return-value-from-function-which-has-observable-subscription-inside)

Comment: @RodrigoSene, hey, it was an `Observable`! Yes, we should work with `Observables` and `Promises` different ways. You wrote "the storage.get return a promise", so i thought that it is promise... Nice to hear, that you founded a solution!

Comment: the return of storage.get is a promise... so ....                                              return Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get('nomeUsuario'));                    i think is not the best way.. but =(