# How to return value inside subscribe Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm new to observables in angular. I have a problem where I want to return a value inside a subscribe method. I have
the following method (`getFirebaseData(idForm:string):observable <any[]>`):

```
getTotalQuestions(idForm:string){
let totalQuestions:number;
this.getFirebaseData(idForm+"/Metadatos")
.subscribe(items => 
  {
    items.map(item => {
      totalQuestions=item.Total;
      console.log(totalQuestions);
    });
  }
);
console.log(totalQuestions);
return totalQuestions;
}
```

the first `console.log(totalQuestions)` prints **4** but the second `console.log(totalQuestions)` prints **undefined**.
I understand that subscribe is an asynchronous operation and for that reason the second `console.log(totalQuestions)` ("In order to write the code") prints undefined, but I can not find the way to return the variable after the subscribe method has been completed. Now, if I change the subscribe to map:

```
getTotalQuestions(idForm:string){
let totalQuestions:number;
this.getFirebaseData(idForm+"/Metadatos")
.subscribe(items => 
  {
    items.map(item => {
      totalQuestions=item.Total;
      console.log(totalQuestions);
    });
  }
);
console.log(totalQuestions);
return totalQuestions;
}
```

the first `console.log(totalQuestions)` does not print anything and the second `console.log(totalQuestions)` prints undefined. It's something that I do not understand why it happens.

I hope you can help me clarify the concept that I do not understand. Thanks!

Comment: Please check the following [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291783/how-to-return-value-from-function-which-has-observable-subscription-inside?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can't directly return *totalQuestions* like that, you need to use a subject to achieve that.

```
getTotalQuestions(idForm:string): Observable<string> {
let totalQuestions:number;
var subject = new Subject<string>();
this.getFirebaseData(idForm+"/Metadatos")
.subscribe(items => {
    items.map(item => {

      totalQuestions=item.Total;
      console.log(totalQuestions);
      subject.next(totalQuestions);
    });
  }
);
  return subject.asObservable();
}
```

Usage: `getTotalQuestion(idForm).subscribe((r)=>console.log(r))`

Comment: We must understand that what I was trying to do was an antipattern, can't force an asynchronous task to be synchronous, for that reason, the methods that include an observable usually return another observable or return nothing. Therefore, I accept this answer as a solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Rajani Kanth Can you check this problem too? It is as same as the above question! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54873434/get-subscribe-data-out-of-subscribe-in-angular

Comment: You the champ! Thanks

Comment: Thanks! It seems crazy that with all the rxjs methods, there is none that work like a deferred promise in angularjs. This works great though.

Comment: @Rajani: its working but i want to return inside subscribe data from service instead of component can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: It worked perfectly, Thanks. It is not my case that I do not use the map section, only the first reply from the subscriber would serve me, but I was obliged, it was the same as what I was specifying.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this I would create a property `totalQuestions$` an observable

In the TS file

```
totalQuestions$ = this.getFirebaseData(idForm + "/Metadatos").pipe(
  map(items => items.reduce((prev, {Total}) => prev + Total), 0)))
)
```

And Now in your template you can use `async` pipe

```
<span>{{ totalQuestions$ | async }}</span>
```

If you would like to use the variable in your TS file, then you can use combination operators like `forkJoin` or combineLatest to access this value

```
newVariable$ = combineLatest([totalQuestions$, ...]).pipe(
  map(([totalQuestions, ... ]) => {
    // Perform an operation here and return a value
  })
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Observable runs when you subscribe to it and what return from subscription is always a subscription object like setInterval. first sample: because this is a async call, second console.log won't wait for subscribe to finish before it executes.

```js
getTotalQuestions(idForm: string) {
  let totalQuestions: number;
  return this.getFirebaseData(idForm + "/Metadatos").pipe(
     map(items =>
      items.map(item => {
        totalQuestions = item.Total;
        console.log(totalQuestions);
      });
    ));
}

getTotalQuestions('231').subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: so here's not returning a value?

Answer (score 1):

[I made a live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4jvxe3?file=app%2Fapp.service.ts).
You do not need to fire the subscription to make transformations to the array or reduce some object to a single value, here is my approached.
**Your service**

```
getTotalQuestions(idForm: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.getFirebaseData(`${idForm}/Metadatos`)
        .pipe(map(items => items
            .map(item => item.Total)
            .reduce((a, b) => a+b), 0));
}
```

**Your component**

```
this.service.getTotalQuestions('id')
    .subscribe(totalQuestions => console.log(totalQuestions));
```