# hi i am getting error in using find function in angular "cannot read property find of undefined

Tags: angular, function, find, using

hi I am trying to display details of a particular id. the details are present in the global variable called 'list' of a service. the id I am getting through route parameters.
the details I need to store in a variable named 'editexpense'.

here is my component :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.a_route.params.subscribe((params)=>this.expense_id=params.Expense_id);
  this.editexpense = this.expense_ser.list
    .find(expense => expense.Expense_id === this.expense_id)
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to return value inside subscribe Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49605090/how-to-return-value-inside-subscribe-angular-4)

Comment: A subscription is an asynchronous operations.When you do the find this.expense_id is unset.
You can put your code in the subscribe function.