# get response of http request in variable

Tags: javascript, angular, web-services

I have a problem,

I have that :

```
  getComposition(){
return this.http.get("/api/setup/composition/getComposition",{responseType: 'text'});
}

    var composition;
this.getComposition().subscribe(data => {composition = data});

console.log(composition);
```

And hen i display composition it return me undefined.. How i can get the result of my request in my var composition ? ...

I have already search a solution...
I'm Using Angular

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you need to put console.log insider subscribe, the subscription will happen after the console.log as its a side effect

Comment: The last line of that function is executed *before* anything in the callback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value from function which has Observable subscription inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291783/how-to-return-value-from-function-which-has-observable-subscription-inside)

Comment: Ok ! I understand.. But is it possible to intiialize the variable composition at initialization of my component? To use this variable in the rest of my code ?

Answer (score 2):

The subscribe probably never got called, I'm just putting it inside `ngOnInit()` but you can fit it in any other function:

```
var composition;

ngOnInit(){

this.getComposition().subscribe(data => {
    this.composition = data
    console.log(this.composition);
  });
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks !  But is it possible to intiialize the variable composition at initialization of my component? To use this variable in the rest of my code ?

Comment: That is exactly what `ngOnInit()` does, initializes the variable (or anything in it) at the initialization of your component.