# My http response saved in var is undefined

Tags: angular

I need to get my user informations. I use this code to do it :

```
export class AuthService {
.
.
.
  private currentUser: Collaborator;

  getCurrentUser() {
    return this.currentUser;
  }

  login(user: Login) {
    this.http.post(this.signInUrl, user).subscribe((data: JwtToken) => {
      this.setToken(data.tokenType + ' ' + data.accessToken);
      this.collabService.getCurrentUser().subscribe((data: Collaborator) => {
        this.currentUser = data;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

But when I use my 'currentUser' var with getter in other component, the value is "undefined".

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
.
.
.
  public currentUser: Collaborator;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentUser = this.authService.getCurrentUser(); --> is undefined
  }
}
```

How I can save the value response in var to use it everywhere ?

Comment: Where and how are you calling `login`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return value from function which has Observable subscription inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291783/how-to-return-value-from-function-which-has-observable-subscription-inside)

Answer (score 1):

**Change your Auth Service according to this: -**

```
export class AuthService {
  public currentUser:any;


  getCurrentUser() {
    return this.currentUser;
  }

  setCurrentUser(user) {
     this.currentUser=user;
  }

  login(user: Login) {
    this.http.post(this.signInUrl, user).map((res: Response) => {
    return res.json();
    });
  }
  getColabUser(){
    this.collabService.getCurrentUser().map((res: Response) => {
    return res.json();
    });
  }

}
```

**Change your HeaderComponent.ts file :-**

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

      public currentUser: Collaborator;

      ngOnInit() {
         this.authService.login(user).subscribe((data)=>{
           this.setToken(data.tokenType + ' ' + data.accessToken); // Either use seperate method in the service file to store token details
             this.collabService.getCurrentUser().subscribe((user) => {
                 this.authService.setCurrentUser(data);
                 this.currentUser = this.authService.getCurrentUser();
          });
         });
      }
    }
```

Now you can get the current user details stored in the AuthService whenever you need via the `getCurrentUser()` method.