# Confusion about observable scope

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs-observables

I have this method for checking if a firestore document exists:

```
rating_exists(userId : string, gameId :  string) : Boolean {
        let exists: boolean = false;
        const docRef = this.afs.collection('ratings').doc(`${userId}_${gameId}`).snapshotChanges()
        .subscribe(x => exists = x.payload.exists);
        return exists;

    }
```

but it seems that this method always returns false.

Its necessary for checking if a user has provided a rating for media. If the user has not provided a rating yet, it should create a rating document for that user

in rating component

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
        if(!this.starsService.rating_exists(this.userId, this.gameId)) {
            console.log("this happened- conditional dose not work!");
            this.starsService.setRating(this.userId, this.gameId, 0)
        }
        this.starsService.getGameRating(this.userId, this.gameId)
        .subscribe(doc => this.stars = doc);    
    }
```

I think that I'm misunderstanding how the scope of observable subscriptions work. console log message always prints despite the fact that document exists for the currently signed in user.

Comment: you need to wait for subscription to finish then you can return.

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291783/how-to-return-value-from-function-which-has-observable-subscription-inside)