# Why is the value not assigned to a variable inside forEach in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

how can I have the return of the variable "this.qdDias" assigned a value to it. I don't know why when I use subscribe I can't get the value at the end of the method. In this "console.log(this.qdDias) " I see the value, but it lowers in the return, the variable becomes undefined again.

```
> obterParametroPrazoMap(nomePrazo: string): number {
>         console.log("Parametro vindo: ", nomePrazo)
>         this.service.obterParametrosgeraisMap().subscribe((data) => {
>             this.listParametrosGerais = data.data;
>             this.listParametrosGerais.forEach((x) =>  (this.listParametrosGerais, x));
>             for (var i = 0; i < this.listParametrosGerais.length; i++) {
>                 console.log("comparado: ", this.listParametrosGerais[i].chavePrimaria.tipoParametro.nomeTipoParametro)
>                 if (this.listParametrosGerais[i].chavePrimaria.tipoParametro.nomeTipoParametro
> === nomePrazo) 
>                 {   
>                     this.qdDias = this.listParametrosGerais[i].quantidadeDiasPrazo;
>                     console.log(this.qdDias)                    
>                     break
>                 }
>             }
>         }                   
>         );
>        return this.qdDias;
>     }
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this that way:

```
Promise.resolve(2);
        Promise.all([
           this.service.obterParametrosgeraisMap()
                .then((lista: any) => {
                    this.listParametrosGerais = lista.data;
                })
            ,
 this.service.obterParametrosEspecificosMap()
                .then((lista: any) => {
                    this.listParametrosEspecifico = lista.data;
                })
        ]).then(() => {    
            this.iniciarVariaveisDicionario();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`return this.qdDias` is out of subscribe scope. But even if the return would be in `subscribe()` it would still not work. You are subscribing to an observable `this.service.obterParametrosgeraisMap().subscribe()` which by nature is asynchronous. But you are trying to treat this function as a synchronous.

Is `this.service.obterParametrosgeraisMap()` an observable that you can subscribe to? Then it should be `this.service.obterParametrosgeraisMap`.

What this does? `this.listParametrosGerais.forEach((x) => (this.listParametrosGerais, x));`

Why use `var`? Should be `const` or `let`?

This could somewhat work but you have to decide if you want to return an observable out of which you take the value. Or you convert it and resolve a promise to keep async pattern https://stackoverflow.com/a/42185519/15439733 or something else.

```js
    function obterParametroPrazoMap(nomePrazo: string): number {
        console.log('Parametro vindo: ', nomePrazo);
        let map;
        this.service.obterParametrosgeraisMap.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(data => map = data);

        this.listParametrosGerais = map?.data;
        this.listParametrosGerais.forEach((x) => (this.listParametrosGerais, x));
        for (var i = 0; i < this.listParametrosGerais.length; i++) {
            console.log('comparado: ', this.listParametrosGerais[i].chavePrimaria.tipoParametro.nomeTipoParametro);
            if (this.listParametrosGerais[i].chavePrimaria.tipoParametro.nomeTipoParametro === nomePrazo) {
                this.qdDias = this.listParametrosGerais[i].quantidadeDiasPrazo;
                console.log(this.qdDias);
                break;
            }
        }

        return this.qdDias;
    }
```

Comment: I tried using the method you wrote, but I couldn't. My service method are these 2 that I'm trying.