# Not getting value in BehaviorSubject angular rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a function like one the below in

service.ts:-

```
itemList$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    getItem() {
    this.http
    .get('APIURL Here')
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
    this.itemList$.next(res.data);
    });
    }
```

Below is my component.ts:-

```
constructor(private myService: MYService) {
    }
    matchItem(idtomatch:any){
    let matchStatus:boolean=false;
    this.myService.itemList$.subscribe((res: any) => {
    for (let val of res) {
    if(idtomatch === res.id){
    matchStatus = true;
    }
    else{
    matchStatus = false;
    }
    }
    });
    return matchStatus;
    }
```

```
this.matchItem(idtomatch)
```

It should return true when idtomatch === res.id else it should return false while it's always returning false.

Comment: can you print that res inside subscribe method

Comment: You are returning the value before the `subscribe` callback had any chance to run.

Comment: @TobiasS. Fromwhere should i return

Comment: You can't return the value of `matchStatus` from the function because you are dealing with asynchronous calls here. Return an Observable instead.

Comment: @Gopal inside the this.myService.itemList$.subscribe((res: any) => {  console.log(res);   }); I am getting the value. also matchStatus become true and false as per value but it's always returning false from let matchStatus:boolean=false;  done know why matchStatus not being overwritwe as per the condition.

Comment: @TobiasS. Then how I can achieve my objective , can you please advise

Comment: @TobiasS. Then how can get goals , please advise

Comment: we don't know what your goals are

Comment: @TobiasS. I want true OR false here this.matchItem(idtomatch) based on match  that's it.

Comment: @TobiasS. any suggestion for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291783/how-to-return-value-from-function-which-has-observable-subscription-inside
this could be helpful for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return value from function which has Observable subscription inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291783/how-to-return-value-from-function-which-has-observable-subscription-inside) I'm voting to close, because I believe you have some misconceptions that need to be clarified first. You are trying to mix synchronous and asynchronous programming here.