# How to get value from asynchronous Angular events returning Promises?

Tags: angular, typescript

Inside subscription blocks I can get the value from my API.

```
var data = null;
this._timinServiceProxy.getDateFromNTP().subscribe(result => {
     data = result;
     console.log(data); // Expected result
});
console.log(data); // It'll be null.
```

I know, it's expected situation because it's an async operation but somehow I need to return result

> .subscribe(result =>

When I tried something like using toPromise()

```
const date = this._timinServiceProxy.getDateFromNTP().toPromise();
return date;
```

It returns `ZoneAwarePromise` and it has `__zone_symbol__value`. __zone_symbol__value holds my correct DateTime object from my API. How can I access this value. I need to access __zone_symbol__value or subscribe result from outside of the scope.

```
getDate(): DateTime {
        if (abp.clock.provider.supportsMultipleTimezone) 
        {
            return DateTime.local().setZone(abp.timing.timeZoneInfo.iana.timeZoneId);
        } 
        else 
        {
            //return DateTime.local();
            
            // RETURN getDateFromNTP()
        }
    }
```

And another thing is I have to return DateTime but my service returns Promise or Observable.

***UPDATE***

Here is my problem on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-pipe-and-luxon-skoqeq?file=app%2Fdate-time-service.ts)

The problem is, by using toPromise I can get DateTime but async methods returns Promise and it's useless because I need only DateTime. I found a hopeless solution like first I called the async method and set it's value to global property then called real method to use it. I wanted to use it in real API but I couldn't do it so I set DateTime static. Check for `date-pipe.component.ts`.

Comment: If you have a `Promise` you either `await` it or attach a `.then(<callback>)` to it to evaluate it.  There's plenty of literature on how that works if you search for it.

Comment: Yes, inside .then block I can access it but it doesn't solve my problem because the value is exists only in .then block. I need to assign this value to property.

Comment: Then `await` it?  You're going to have to make everything up the call chain `async`.  The only thing you have outside of that is to write your own polling event loops.  This problem you have is extremely common, but trying to get away from asynchronous programming with it is picking an unnecessary fight with your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return value from function which has Observable subscription inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291783/how-to-return-value-from-function-which-has-observable-subscription-inside)

Comment: The title does not match the body. Getting subscription information is easy; just set a variable to the result of `.subscribe()`; it returns a `Subscription` object. You can use that to unsubscribe. What you're asking in the body is how to return the data emitted by an observable; something that's been asked and answered before.

Comment: @possum I did it also ChatGPT suggested it but it returns Promise<DateTime>. I couldn't convert it to DateTime.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I saw the topic and tried but it didn't work. When I tried over promise it returns undefined or `ZoneAwarePromise`. The answer about firstValueFrom worked but I needed to upgrade RxJs to version 7. Can we make it by using RxJs 6?

Comment: You just can't get data from an asynchronous method before the method has gotten the data. That's it. You can't eat a pizza before it's delivered.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Understood but `let myDate = await firstValueFrom(this._timinServiceProxy.getDateFromNTP());` solved my problem. I got the data like inside subscribe event body but the difference is I can use myDate property on global scope.

Answer (score 1):

RxJS now suggests using `firstValueFrom` or `lastValueFrom` for this. More details at https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise

For your use case, I think something like this should work. Please note that both of those needs to be awaited for them to work as you wanted.

```js
    async getData() {
        let myDate = await firstValueFrom(this._timinServiceProxy.getDateFromNTP());
        console.log(myDate);
    }
```

Also, if you want to use it in `ngOnInit()`, you'll need to make that async as well.

```js
async ngOnInit() {
    let data = await this.getData();
}
```

Comment: You're just quoting the functions that replace `toPromise`.  That isn't a helpful answer because, if you read the question, it is what they already have in the `Promise` those return.

Comment: The original post is a little unclear since it doesn't make clear what scope it's from, nor does it make explicit that .getDateFromNTP() returns an Observable (though that looks to be the case in this context). Assuming the scope of the OP's code is an async method though, the suggestion to use firstValueFrom() looks right to me. .toPromise is deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: YES, it worked but the thing is firstValueFrom released with RxJs 7 and the project has RxJs 6 so I had to comment 50 lines of _observableOf code. It's a company project so my movement area is limited. Can I make it without firstValueFrom? It didn't work with Promise. I use await after toPromise() but it returns ZoneAwarePromise otherwise firstValueFrom directly returns DateTime

Comment: Is this GitHub issue thread helpful? : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/1429

Comment: @CaptainTaro Here's a bare minimum working example of `toPromise`. Is there something different from your setup? Can you try to edit that to reproduce your issue in this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m87s4z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @therearedoors I didn't see the issue before, I'll try tomorrow morning.

Comment: @V.S Thanks. I'll try one more time. If it don't work I'll try to move these codes to stackblitz.

Comment: @V.S sorry for false alarm. It didn't work. I guess I missee console.log and returned value. It still returns `ZoneAwarePromise ` but inside the method it logs DateTime. I updated the question with stackblitz link. You may check it. Thanks

Comment: You'll need to make the `ngOnInit` async as well and then await your dateService call. I've updated my answer above, and also updated the code (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-pipe-and-luxon-pvvmjw?file=app%2Fdate-pipe.component.ts)