# Getting boolean value from ReplaySubject<boolean> asObservable

Tags: angular, authentication

I'm following thinkster tutorial for Angular2, and I made these two for checking if the user is authenticated:

```
private isAuthenticatedSubject = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
public isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticatedSubject.asObservable();
```

now, in my auth-gaurd.service.ts, I want to check the **boolean** value of *isAuthenticated*. How can I do that? I want to do something like this:

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean> {
    //THIS IS NOT WORKING! 
    //Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'Observable<boolean>' and 'boolean'
    if (this.userService.isAuthenticated.take(1) === false) { 
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    }
    return this.userService.isAuthenticated.take(1);
}
```

You can find the complete code from thinkster [here](https://github.com/gothinkster/angular2-realworld-example-app)

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089977/how-to-get-current-value-of-rxjs-subject-or-observable/37089997#37089997

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, The problem is that 1) I used ReplaySubject instead of BehaviorSubject because I'll be able to create isAuthenticatedSubject without an initial value and 2) I want to use *isAuthenticated*

Comment: I haven't checked `ReplaySubject` perhaps it works the same as `BehaviorSubject`. Have you tried?

Comment: Perhaps you can make it shared, subscribe to it and store the value in a property in subscribe.

Comment: Please add the code to the question. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, thanks, I did it by subscribing to *isAuthenticated*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Günter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer) mentioned in the comments, I solved it by subscribing to the *isAuthenticated*. The code should be like this:

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean> {

    var isAuthenticated = false;

    // Check if the user is authenticated
    this.userService.isAuthenticated.take(1).subscribe(function (data) {
        isAuthenticated = data;
    });

    // If the user is not authenticated, redirect to Login page
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    }

    return this.userService.isAuthenticated.take(1);
}
```