# RxJS 6: Why calling value on BehaviorSubject is a bad thing? (according to no-subject-value lint rule)

Tags: rxjs, lint

For me it's advantage of BehaviorSubject over Subject, that the first one always returns value, so why one of the rxjs lint rules says it's forbidden?

example:

```
private _languageSource$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>("EN");

get language(): string {
  return this._languageSource$.value;
}
```

Comment: This comment explains this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089977/how-to-get-current-value-of-rxjs-subject-or-observable#comment77420190_37089997