# How to get only latest value from subscribe in angular 4

Tags: angular

How to get only latest value from subscribe in angular 4?

```
this.AbcSrvice.value.subscribe(data => {console.log(data)})
```

Comment: is `data` a list? or an object? or is it a variable

Comment: You should probably check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089977/how-to-get-current-value-of-rxjs-subject-or-observable

Comment: Please add more context.

Comment: I am subscriblng a boolean  BehaviorSubject, so i want only latest value or last value from observable

Answer (score 2):

Use the last operator : https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/last.html

```
import { last } 'rxjs/operators';


this.AbcSrvice.value
.pipe(last())
.subscribe(data => {console.log(data)});
```

Comment: its not useless, its impossible to answer the question without knowing more information

Comment: why? he just wants the "latest value" emitted, who cares what the value is

Comment: for all we know, the OP wants the latest entry in an array, or they could want the updated value, in both cases, you dont need the `.pipe()`

Comment: @mast3rd3mon if it was the latest entry in an array, I'm hoping that the OP would not need post a question on SO... and this would not be related to `subscribe` either. However, I can understand that the question might seem unclear; and maybe I did not understand what OP meant either... just have to wait for them

Comment: Above code is not working for me

Comment: @ShivajiWatekar: `not working` meaning ...?

Comment: @David I am subscriblng a boolean  BehaviorSubject, so i want only latest value or last value from observable

Comment: @ShivajiWatekar And what do you get using `last`?