# How to emit only one or last value of Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Parent HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let doc of documents">
    <child [clickEvent]="eventSubject.asObservable()" [document]="doc"></child>
 </ng-container>
```

Parent Class:

```
eventSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
onclick(event)  {
    this.eventSubject.next(event)
}
```

Child Class:

```
@Input() keyEvent: Observable<boolean>;

this.keyEvent
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
```

Because I bind the event inside an *ngFor, it sends the value as much as my array length. Its essential that I get the last or one value of the emitted in the observable. What can be done?

I tried using the take and last operators, but they complete the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the if condition in HTML

### Solution 1

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let doc of documents; last as last">
    <child *ngIf= "!last" [document]="doc"></child>
    <child *ngIf= "last" [clickEvent]="eventSubject.asObservable()" [document]="doc"></child>
 </ng-container>
```

### Solution 2

Just handle it in `ts` file instead. Make the following changes -

### in html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let doc of documents; last as last">
    <child [clickEvent]="handlClick(last)" [document]="doc"></child>
 </ng-container>
```

### in ts

```
handlClick(isLast){
   if(isLast){
     return eventSubject.asObservable();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject`. It has `getValue()` method which gives you current emitted value.

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37089977/7812112)