# Convert Observable<boolean> to a boolean value

Tags: angular

This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089977/how-to-get-current-value-of-rxjs-subject-or-observable) for several reasons.  1.  I am using angular 7 not angular 2.  2.  I am using rxjs6 not rxjs5.  I have no benefit in learning these earlier versions as they are extinct.  3.  I am asking about an Observable(boolean) concept when this question does not mention Observable(boolean)

I created an Observable value that I want true/false from it.  Here is my code in nav.component.ts file

```
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  private $loggedin: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor( private auth: AuthenticationService){}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.$loggedin = this.auth.$isLoggedinSource;
    console.log('am i logged in ', this.$loggedin);
  }
```

The console output is :

```
am i logged in Observable {_isScalar: false, source: BehaviorSubject}
               source: BehaviorSubject {_isScalar: false, observers: 
               Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: 
               false, …}
               _isScalar: false ...
```

How can I get a boolean, true/false value out of $loggedin?

Comment: There is no relation between rxjs library and angular. Your question is totally addressed in the duplicate flag. if `$isLoggedinSource` is a BehaviorSubject as your  tag suggest it, then you just can get the value `this.auth.$isLoggedinSource.getValue();`

Comment: Florian, I am not using angular2 nor rxjs5 in my app.  I have not desire to learn this outdated technology.  I am on the cutting edge with angular 7 and rxjs6.  This is my first app.  The question is two years old.  A lifetime in software development.  BehaviorSubject is not mentioned in that question.

Comment: `1.` rxjs is just a library, rxjs6 replaced rxjs5, however your question doesn't address a feature specific of rxjs6. `2.` your question has two tags: `angular` and `behaviorsubject`, so yes, BehaviorSubject is mentioned here.

Comment: BehaviorSubject is NOT mentioned in the question you are referring to.  I got an outstanding state of the art answer on this question.  I am happy. I hope another person finds this current answer useful too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two ways that you can use to unwrap the value of an Observable.

1. By using the `async` pipe in your Template:

   `<p>Am I logged In: {{ $isLoggedinSource | async }}</p>`

**OR**

2. By `subscribe`ing to the Observable in your Component:

---

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

...

subscription: Subscription;

...

this.subscription = this.$loggedin
  .subscribe(data => console.log('am i logged in ', data));

...

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

#### Which one to use?

If this `$loggedin` Observable is recurring, and you use the Approach 2, then you'll have to assign it to a `Subscription` typed property and then call `unsubscribe` on it inside the `ngOnDestroy`.

With first approach, you aren't really required to do that.

Comment: SiddAjmera,  Thank you for the outstanding answer.  I never even thought of using ngOnDestroy().  It is necessary for memory leaks I think.  I totally understand the second approach, implemented it and it works!

Comment: In a similar project I've tried to implement the `async` method, it gives another error:
`"Type boolean | null is not assigneble to type boolean"`

(Using angular 15, rxjs 7.8)

Also found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61781052/2489730

Answer (score 4):

If you don't wanna subscribe, you can get the observable value using `async` and `await`, but to do this, you have to converte the `Observable` into a `Promise.

Something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public loggedin: boolean;
  public otherValue: boolean;

  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedin = await this.auth.$isLoggedinSource.toPromise();
    this.otherValue = await this.auth.$otherObservable.toPromise();
  }
}
```

[You can see it working in this stackblitz link.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2yz2gp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working in the link that you have provided

Answer (score 3):

You have to subscribe to it. Right now you are logging the Observable object itself, but what you have to do is subscribe to it so when it is resolved your subscription will listen to it and then print whatever it is resolving.

Answer (score 2):

You have to subscribe to observables to get the data.

```
this.$loggedin.subscribe((data: boolean) => 
{
    console.log('am i logged in ', data);
}
```

Comment: You're not required to set the `data` parameter's type as a `boolean`. This should already be done for you when you casted `Observable` to a union type of `boolean`.