# How to change value in object in array BehaviorSubject?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a initial data as: `const menuItems = [{id: 1, active: false}, {id: 2, active: false}]`

```
  public menuSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<MenuItem[]>(menuItems);
  public menu$ = this.menuSubject$.asObservable();
```

I try to modify element where `id: 1`:

```
modify(id: number) {
   const menuItemsUpdated = this.menuSubject$.getValue().map((item) => {
      if(item.id === id) {
         return {...item, active: true};
      }
      return item;
   });

    this.menuSubject$.next(menuItemsUpdated);
}
```

I wonder is it properly way to do that using async `getValue()` and pushing this back?

Comment: it is fine. more rxjs way would be to create updates$ and merge it with the original stream to build the resulting value, but  in your particular sutuation it woul just be a more comlicated way of solving the same problem

Comment: Could you share this described aproach?

Comment: My code modifies all items of array. So something is wrong

Comment: it is not modifying all of the items. why did you think it does?

Comment: Sorry it was, I had mistake in `_item` and `item`.

Comment: This is a good question and I asked pretty much the thing a few months back ["RXJS - BehaviorSubject: proper use of .value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62262008/rxjs-behaviorsubject-proper-use-of-value).  You may find some of the answers interesting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems ok. I would do the same thing .

Comment: The template is blinking when whole object re-rendered. That is disandvantage