# How to get BehaviourSubject value in other component if I type the component url directly?

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

Let's simplify the question. Say the angular application only has a few components. In app component html,

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The ts file we inject a service to get navigation menu. The service contains a BehaviourSubject to handle menu items.

```
@Injectable({
     providendIn: 'root'
})
export class AppService {
    public items = new BehaviourSubject<Item[]>([]);
    public getMenu() {
         return this.http.get<Item[]>(this.url);
    }
    public getItems() {
        return this.items.value;
    }
}
```

In app component ts file.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.service.getMenu().subscribe(
      res => {
          this.items = res;
          this.service.items.next(this.items);
      });
}
```

So far so good. Then in my nav component I can receive the items.

```
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
    items: any;
    constructor(private service: AppService){}
    ngOnInit() {
          this.items = this.service.getItems();
    }
}
```

Then in Nav html I have

```
   <span *ngFor="let item of items">
     <div>{{item.name}}</div>
   </span>
```

So the normal step is to go to http://localhost:4200 then navigation bar is displayed correctly. However if I type the url of another component directly. Say

```
http://localhost:4200/app/one
```

It seems the page loads component `one` first. The navigation bar is rendered before get the menu items. Actually I log the items in component one, it is empty. Eventually it also goes to app component but it is too late.

So my question is that I want to get menu items in the very first place. Whatever I typed any url I can always get the navbar menu items and rendered correctly. I doubt that I used `BehaviouSubject` wrongly. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that your nav component only sets the value of `items` one time.  Since your behavior subject has a default value of empty array, when `OneComponent.ngOnInit` calls `service.getItems()` it receives an empty array and that value is never updated on further emissions.

There is a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62262008/rxjs-behaviorsubject-proper-use-of-value) that explores using `BehaviorSubject.value` appropriately.  I would discourage use of `.value` in your case.

It actually makes the code much more complicated, and is breaking the "observability" of the data flow.

Since `NavComponent` uses `AppService` directly, `AppComponent` doesn't need to be involved at all!  Just let `NavComponent` subscribe to items directly.

Also, it seems unnecessarily complex to have the `AppService` call a service method to get the items, then another service method to have the service push the new value out.  It would be much simpler if the service was responsible for pushing out the newest values and consumers of the service simply subscribe to the observable.

service:

```js
export class AppService {
  private items = new BehaviorSubject<Item[]>([]);
  public items$ = this.items.asObservable();

  public getMenu() {
    return http.get().pipe(
      tap(items => this.items.next(items))
    );
  }
}
```

The code above allows consumers to simply subscribe to `items$` and receive the latest value automatically.  Whenever `getMenu()` is called, it will push the newest value through the subject.

The `NavComponent` can use this directly, and the `AppComponent` doesn't need to do anything:

nav component:

```js
export class NavComponent {
  items$ = this.service.items$;

  constructor(private service: AppService){ }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getMenu().subscribe();
  }
}
```

```html
<span *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">
  <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
</span>
```

app component:

```js
export class AppComponent  {

}
```

LOL, nothing in the app component.  Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66693555-a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts)

So, going back to your original question:

> How to get BehaviorSubject value in other component if I type the component url directly?

The overall idea is to reference the BehaviorSubject as an observable, so you always receive the most recent value; don't use `.value` to pull out a single value at one moment in time.

Comment: The code works just a little slow when rending the navigation bar. But really thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe the items BehaviourSubject in component one.

Here is my solution:

```
   items: any;
   constructor(private service: AppService){}
   ngOnInit() {
      this.service.items.subcribe(items => this.items = items);
   }
```

Because the `Component One` was initialized before the get request done. At this time, the `BehaviourSubject` didn't receive any new value so it emitted the seed value (an empty array). So I think `subscribe()` will work.

Comment: That would require subscribing to menuservice in every component you can navigate to directly manually. Seems rather tedious to me.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the Menu Bar rendered on any page immediately?
If that's true, I think putting your initializing code into the `app.component.t`s is not quite what you want.

I would say that using APP_INITIALIZER to load menu items before your application starts might be a better choice. See e.g.
[Angular: How to correctly implement APP_INITIALIZER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707830/angular-how-to-correctly-implement-app-initializer)