# Toggling value of behavior subject without using getValue

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I want to toggle the `boolean` value of my behavior subject. I'm currently achieving this by using the Behavior Subject's `getValue()` method. This isn't ideal as I'm effectively taking my reactive, declarative code and turning it into imperative style code by pulling the data out of the data stream:

```
private userIsRegistering: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
userIsRegistering$: Observable<boolean> = this.userIsRegistering.asObservable();

toggleUserIsRegistering() {
   this.userIsRegistering.next(!this.userIsRegistering.getValue());
}
```

I want to do this in a reactive way by somehow making use of RXJS operators and working within the data stream. I can't seem to figure how to go about this?

I've seen this SO post:

[RXJS - BehaviorSubject: proper use of .value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62262008/rxjs-behaviorsubject-proper-use-of-value)

But the issue with this is that the `myBool$` Observable only gets triggered when the `myToggle$` Observable is triggered.

I need the `userIsRegistering` Subject/Behavior Subject to have an initial value as I am deriving state from this Observable in other parts of the service:

```
accountAction$: Observable<{type: string, linkLabel: string, linkText: string, buttonAction: string}> = this.userIsRegistering$.pipe(
    map(userIsRegistering => {
      return {
        type: userIsRegistering ? 'Register' : 'Login',
        linkLabel: userIsRegistering ? 'Already have an account?' : 'No account?',
        linkText: userIsRegistering ? 'Login' : 'Register',
        buttonAction: userIsRegistering ? 'Register' : 'Login',
      }
    })
  );
```

If the Behavior Subject did not have an initial value, the above `accountAction$` Observable would not be triggered when the service initializes.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hello,
I recommend you to move data to a service, and change data in the service and move the data with help an Observable
Here is an example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qngq7c?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the issue with this is that the myBool$ Observable only gets triggered when the myToggle$ Observable is triggered.

If you simply need to ensure derived observables emit an initial value, just use [`startWith`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith):

```js
  private myToggle$ = new Subject<void>();

  private myBool$ = this.myToggle$.pipe(
      scan(previous => !previous, true),
      startWith(true),
  );

  state$ = this.myBool$.pipe(
    map(bool => bool ? STATE_A : STATE_B)
  );
```

Here, `myToggle$` is simply a trigger (*emitted value is not used*).  `myBool$` uses [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) to emit the new state based on the previous emission.  `startWith` will initially emit the default value.

---

If you need the multicast / replay functionality like `BehaviorSubject` provides, you could simply use [`shareReplay(1)`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay):

```js
  private myBool$ = this.myToggle$.pipe(
      scan(previous => !previous, MY_BOOL_INITIAL),
      startWith(MY_BOOL_INITIAL),
      shareReplay(1)
  );
```

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-75274319?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demo.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did try using the scan operator before but couldn't get it to work. Seems to be working correctly now

Answer (score 1):

The proper reactive way to achieve this toggle is withLatestFrom pipeable operator IMHO. You need something like this:

```
anotherObservable$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.userIsRegistering)
).subscribe(userIsRegisteringValue => {
  this.userIsRegistering.next(!userIsRegisteringValue);
})
```

Here you can find withLatestFrom documentation:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom

Because of BehaviourSubject dual nature you don't need **.asObservable()**

> I need the userIsRegistering Subject/Behavior Subject to have an initial value

In your case userIsRegistering already has initial value which is false.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's not worth it to create a separate "toggle" mechanic, and it's simpler just "set" the boolean value instead.

In this case, you would need to emit both the "state" and the value of "myBool", so we can wrap them into a single view model object:

```js
  private myBool$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);

  vm$ = this.myBool$.pipe(
    map(myBool => ({ 
      state: myBool ? STATE_A : STATE_B, 
      myBool
    }))
  );

  setMyBool(value: boolean) {
    this.myBool$.next(value);
  }
```

Then from your template you can call `setMyBool(!vm.myBool)`.

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-75274319-b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demo.