# Is it a bad practise to access a BehaviorSubject via .value?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have heard that it is considered good practise to expose your `BehaviorSubject`s via  `.asObservable()` and create an API to add/remove elements from it.

Is the below implementation the recommended way to do that?

I've never used `.value` on a BehaviorSubject before. I always assumed that was bad practise (as opposed to subscribing).
Any and all advice on how this implementation could be improved would be greatly appreciated.

```
export class TodoService {
    private _todos: BehaviorSubject<Todo[]> = new BehaviorSubject([] as Todo[]);

    constructor() {
    }

    get todos() {
        return this._todos.asObservable();
    }

    public addTodo(todo: Todo) {
        this._todos.next([...this._todos.value, todo]);
    }

    public removeTodo(index: number) {
        const tempArray = [...this._todos.value];
        tempArray.splice(index, 1);
        this._todos.next(tempArray);
    }

    public updateTodo(index: number, todo: Todo) {
        const todos = this._todos.value;
        todos[index] = todo;
        this._todos.next([...todos]);
    }

    public getTodo(index: number): Todo {
        return this._todos.value[index];
    }

    public clearCompleted() {
        this._todos.next(this._todos.value.filter(todo => !todo.completed));
    }
}
```

Comment: It is ok, this is how state is built based on `Subject`. Great state service :)

Comment: Maybe you'll find some of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62262008/rxjs-behaviorsubject-proper-use-of-value) helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089977/how-to-get-current-value-of-rxjs-subject-or-observable/37089997#37089997