# Create a computed Subject for another Subject in ReactiveX

Tags: c#, functional-programming, rxjs, reactive, rx.net

`Subject` in RX can store value and subscribed by others. May I know if there a way to make a `Subject` depends on another `Subject` as an computed version of the source `Subject`?

Answer (score 1):

In a way... yes!

It is possible to define observable streams from one another.  So while it may not really make sense to create a "computed subject" from another subject, you can create an observable that depends on a subject, yielding an observable that emits whenever the source subject emits.

Example: ([StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66363868?file=index.ts))

```js
const user$ = new Subject<User>();  // Subject source

const greeting$ = user$.pipe(       // Observable source
    map(user => `Hello ${user.name}!`)
);

user$.subscribe(
    val => console.log('user$: ', val)
);

greeting$.subscribe(
    val => console.log('greeting$: ', val)
);

user$.next({ id: 1, name: 'mannok'   });
user$.next({ id: 2, name: 'BizzyBob' });

// Output:
// > { id: 1, name 'mannok' }
// > Hello, mannok!
// > { id: 2, name 'BizzyBob' }
// > Hello, BizzyBob!
```

`greeting$` is derived from `user$`, so whenever `user$` subject emits, `greeting$` will also emit.

Comment: Thank so much. I love you example. btw, for anyone looking for C# solution you may use `observable.Select(/* you lambda function used to transform */)`

Comment: btw, for `Subject`, I can get its current value by accessing `.Value` (in Rx.NET). The solution you provided cannot get current value of `greeting$`. Any suggestion to retrieve current value of derived `Observable`?

Comment: I'm not specifically familiar with `Rx.NET`, but generally observables are just streams that values flow through and the observable itself doesn't keep track of the last emitted value.  Even basic `Subject`s in rxjs do not provide this functionality ([Get value from Subject?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37089997/1858357)), but [BehaviorSubject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject) have a `getValue()` method for that purpose.  However, observables derived from subjects/behavior subjects are just plain observables and don't have the `getValue()` method. :-(