# How to toggle value in ReplaySubject?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to get current value and invert it:

```
public controlActive$ = new ReplaySubject<Tool>();
if(this.type == "A") {
   this.controlActive$.next(!controlActive$.getValue());
}
```

How to do that more elegant?

Comment: How are you using this, in what context?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `BehaviorSubject.getValue()` is discouraged in general ([see this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089977/how-to-get-current-value-of-rxjs-subject-or-observable#comment77420190_37089997)). Instead you should subscribe to the Subject even though it's not a very elegant solution:

```
this.controlActive$
  .pipe(
    take(1),
  )
  .subscribe(value => this.controlActive$.next(!value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this only needed in the initialization? if so, you could use a BehaviorSubject instead:

```
public controlActive$: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

public constructor(private type: string) {
    this.controlActive$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.type === 'A');
}
```

the initial value would be `true` then, if type === 'A'.

To toggle it, your method could then be applied:

```
public toggle() {
    this.controlActive$.next(!this.controlActive$.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ReplaySubject` does not have contain `getValue()` function or a `.value` getter. For that you'd need to use the `BehaviorSubject` that accepts a default value.

```js
private controlActiveSource: BehaviorSubject<Tool> = new BehaviorSubject<Tool>(null); // <-- needs a default value
public controlActive$: Observable<Tool> = this.controlActiveSource.asObservable();

if (this.type == "A") {
   this.controlActive$.next(!this.controlActive$.getValue());
}
```

---

The topic of "elegance" is subjective. Some would say ([including the core lead of RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45227115/6513921)) using the `getValue()` is inelegant and an anti-pattern since it allows synchronous access to the value.

In that case you could decouple the current state from the multi-cast observable.

```js
private controlActive: boolean = false;
private controlActiveSource: ReplaySubject<Tool> = new ReplaySubject<<Tool>(1);
public controlActive$: Observable<Tool> = this.controlActiveSource.asObservable();

if (this.type == "A") {
  this.toggleControl();
  this.controlActive$.next(this.controlActive);
}

toggleControl() {
  this.controlActive = !this.controlActive;
}
```