# How to remove element from BehaviorSubject array?

Tags: rxjs

There is an array in `public users = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>([])`.

I want to delete element from this observable and refresh it.

My solution is:

```
const idRemove = 2;
this.users.next(this.user.getValue().filter((u) => u.id !== idRemove)
```

But I seem I use wrong way of using RXJS

Answer (score 2):

#### Toward Idiomatic RxJS

Using subscribe instead of `.value`.

```ts
interface User {
  id: number
}

const users$ = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>([
  {id:1}, 
  {id:2}, 
  {id:3}
]);

function removeId(idRemove: number) {
  users$.pipe(
    take(1),
    map(us => us.filter(u => u.id !== idRemove))
  ).subscribe(
    users$.next.bind(users$)
  );
}

users$.subscribe(us =>
  console.log("Current Users: ", us)
);

removeId(2);
removeId(1);
removeId(3);
```

Output:

```html
Current Users:  [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 } ]
Current Users:  [ { id: 1 }, { id: 3 } ]
Current Users:  [ { id: 3 } ]
Current Users:  []
```

Comment: this works, but I do not fully understand why once `removeId(0)` is called, it is not removing the first element each time a new entry is added

Comment: ah it is because of `take`: `Takes the first count values from the source, then completes.`

Answer (score 0):

To handle state within RxJS pipes you can use the [Scan](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/scan) operator

> Useful for encapsulating and managing state. Applies an accumulator (or "reducer function") to each value from the source after an initial state is established -- either via a seed value (second argument), or from the first value from the source.

```js
const { Subject, merge } = rxjs;
const { scan, map } = rxjs.operators;

// This function is used to apply new users to the state of the scan
const usersFn = users => state => users
// This function is used to remove all matching users with the given id from the state of the scan
const removeFn = removeId => state => state.filter(user => user.id !== removeId)

// This Subject represents your old user BehaviorSubject
const users$$ = new Subject()
// This Subject represents the place where this.users.next(this.user.getValue().filter((u) => u.id !== idRemove) was called
const remove$$ = new Subject()

// This is your new user$ Observable that handles a state within its pipe. Use this Observable in all places where you need your user Array instead of the user BehaviorSubject
const user$ = merge(
  // When users$$ emits the usersFn is called with the users argument (1. time)
  users$$.pipe(map(usersFn)),
  // When remove$$ emits the removeFn is called with the removeId argument (1. time)
  remove$$.pipe(map(removeFn))
).pipe(
  // Either the usersFn or removeFn is called the second time with the state argument (2. time)
  scan((state, fn) => fn(state), [])
)

// Debug subscription
user$.subscribe(console.log)

// Test emits
users$$.next([
  {id: 1, name: "first"},
  {id: 2, name: "second"}
])
remove$$.next(2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Ben Lesh (main Contributor of RxJS) wrote an anser about why not to use `getValue` in RxJS: [The only way you should be getting values "out of" an Observable/Subject is with subscribe!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089977/how-to-get-current-value-of-rxjs-subject-or-observable/45227115#45227115)

Answer (score -1):

Using `getValue()` is discouraged in general for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089977/how-to-get-current-value-of-rxjs-subject-or-observable) even though I'm sure there are exception where it's fine to use it. So a better way is subscribing to get the latest value and then changing it:

```
this.users
  .pipe(take(1)) // take(1) will make sure we're not creating an infinite loop
  .subscribe(users => {
    this.users.next(users.filter((u) => u.id !== idRemove);
  });
```