# Angular returning observable object from Objservable Array of objects:

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables, rxjs-observables

I would like to return an Observable object from a Observable Array or objects. getTodoById()
I tried to return by using pipe & map operators.
Err messsages:

> Type 'Observable<Todo | undefined>' is not assinable to type 'Observable'. Type 'Todo | undefined is not assignable to type 'Todo'. ts(2322)

I tried assigning "?" sign but it wasn't very useful. Maybe I did it wrong.
This is my current code.
I tried Observable<Todo | undefined> as a return type to getById() it showed the same error.

todo service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of, Subscription, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FilterBy } from '../models/filterBy.model';
import { SortBy } from '../models/sortBy.model';
import { Todo } from '../models/todo.model';

// this is BehaviorSubject - Can get .next
  private _todos$ = new BehaviorSubject<Todo[]>([])

  // this is an Observable - we CANNOT do .next.
  // It acts like a getter - You can list to it's changes
  // this makes a good separation!
  public todos$ = this._todos$.asObservable();

      public getById(id: string): Observable<Todo> {
    return this.todos$.pipe(map(todos=> todos.find(todo => todo._id === id)))
  }
```

todo model:

```
export interface Todo {
  _id: string,
  title:string,
  date:Date,
  isDone:boolean,
  importance:number
}
```

Comment: Observable<Todo | undefined>

Comment: Didn't help.  to add :    Observable<Todo | undefined> as a return type to getVyId @MikeOne

Comment: [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the found item or `undefined`.  Changing return type of function should fix.  Were you getting a different error after the change?

Comment: Could you try `.filter()` instead of map and find?

Comment: @BizzyBob - I got the exact error after changing the return type ( Added undefined)

Comment: @leila-m : did you mean :  return this.todos$.pipe(filter(todo => todo._id === id))

Comment: @leila-m: now I am getting error: Type 'Observable<Todo[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Todo>'. Type 'Todo[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Todo': _id, title, date, isDone, importance ts(2322)

Comment: See if you can reproduce in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to add filter operator

```
return this.todos$.pipe(
  map(todos=> todos.find(todo => todo._id === id)),
  filter(todo => !!todo)
)
```

Comment: Why use filter ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to add undefined as a return type to getById because you are using find() and typescript is smart enough to know that your array will not always return a value.

```js
  public getById(id: string): Observable<Todo | undefined> {
    return this.todos$.pipe(map(todos=> todos.find(todo => todo._id === id)))
  }
```

Or if you don't want to return undefined as a return value you can use casting as follows:

```js
  public getById(id: string): Observable<Todo> {
    return this.todos$.pipe(map(todos=> todos.find(todo => todo._id === id))) as Observable<Todo>
  }
```

but I prefer the first solution

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers and trying to help. I decided to go for a simpler way which is:

```
  public getById(id: string): Todo | undefined{
    const todos = this._todos$.getValue();
    return todos.find(todo => todo._id === id);
  }
```

Comment: "Important note from the author of RxJS 5: Using getValue() is a HUGE red flag you're doing something wrong. It's there as an escape hatch. Generally everything you do with RxJS should be declarative. getValue() is imperative. If you're using getValue(), there's a 99.9% chance you're doing something wrong or weird. – 
Ben Lesh
 Jul 21 '17 at 0:01

Link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089977/how-to-get-current-value-of-rxjs-subject-or-observable (see the answers)