# Trigger BehaviorSubject with same value after Mutation

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an BehaviorSubject on which I have changes via mutation (don't ask why, but sadly there is no other options to change the values). I want to trigger the BehaviorSubject for subscriptions on the changes

is there an other option than

```
  triggerNext() {
        this.uploadFiles$.next(this.uploadFiles$.getValue());
    }
```

to trigger it? It works, but is far from pretty

Comment: If you are mutating the value at some point in your code, maybe you should call .next() with the reference to the mutated value at that point.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should subscribe to the Subject to get its value because this approach is considered an anti-pattern ([How to get current value of RxJS Subject or Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089977/how-to-get-current-value-of-rxjs-subject-or-observable?rq=3#comment77420190_37089997)).

However, I think it depends on your usecase. If you know that `this.uploadFiles$` never completes and serves as "state" I think I'd do it the same way as you did because it's much more readable than the following:

```
this.uploadFiles$
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(val => this.uploadFiles$.next(val));
```