# Is using getValue() on BehaviorSubject bad practice?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Ben Lesh and Angular University have contradictory stands on `BehaviorSubject`.

I am confused about the following. I have read from Ben Lesh himself that using `getValue()` on a behavior subject is a huge code smell.

He said [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45227115/12232720):

> ### The only way you *should*  be getting values "out of" an Observable/Subject is with subscribe!
>
> If you're using `getValue()` you're doing something imperative in
> declarative paradigm. It's there as an escape hatch, but **99.9% of
> the time you should NOT use `getValue()`.**

However, in [this](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/) blog article from Angular University, I have read this:

> Subject has one particularity that prevents us from using it to build
> observable data services: if we subscribe to it we won't get the last
> value, we will have to wait until some part of the app calls `next()`.
>
> This poses a problem especially in bootstrapping situations, where the
> app is still initializing and not all subscribers have registered, for
> example not all `async` pipes had the chance to register themselves
> because not all templates are yet initialized.
>
> The solution for this is to use a BehaviorSubject. [Using getValue]
> makes the BehaviorSubject the heart of the observable data service.

Can someone please clarify these obviously contradicting stands?

Please note that I am not asking for an opinion. The concept of a data service with RxJS is a standard way of managing state. I am asking only asking for a clarification on these two condradictions.

Comment: It depends a bit of what you want to achieve. RXJS ist more for streaming data and combine different stream and not for state handling. If it is more about state handling you want to have give signals a try. there you can access the state without any side effects. But there are other challenges ;) both can be used together ... but also good knowledge about both is needed.

Comment: In the blog sentence "**This** makes the BehaviorSubject the heart of the observable data service, we don't need much more to build one. Let's take a look at a concrete example.", **this** refers to the first sentence of the paragraph ("The solution for this is to use a BehaviorSubject. What this type of subject does it that it will return upon subscription the last value of the stream, or an initial state if no value was emitted yet"), not to the possibility of using `getValue()`, which is just an additional (imperative) API.

Answer (score 0):

some angular developer embrace using rxjs at every possible place. It may be harder to do, but you will be sure that your values are always computed up to date. The problem with `.getValue()` is you are taking a snapshot at some particular point of time - instead of creating the dependant value as observable. for example

```
class SomeService {
  items$ = BehaviorSubject<Item[]>([]);
...
class SomeComponent {
  items = this.service.items$.getValue();
}
```

and items are updated for example by pressing refresh button - new items will be emitted to the subject, but component will be showing old items. so here not leaving rxjs world and subscribing with `| async` pipe would work better.

however there are usecases where `.getValue()` could be really helpful. lets say you have filters stored in it

```
filters$ = new BehaviorSubject<{a?: string; b?: string}>({});
```

and you want to update partialy this filters when either of filters changes. the implementation could look like this

```
updateFilter(name: string; value: string) {
  this.filters$.next({
    ... this.filters$.getValue(), // taking old values
    [name]: value // overwriting one of filters
  })
}
```

of course it could be done without this method, but it is cleaner and simpler than more rxjsish solutions and obviously not dangerous in this particular case.

regarding the Angular University article:
this phrase is slightly broken and doesn't follow the previous text:
"The solution for this is to use a BehaviorSubject. [Using getValue] makes the BehaviorSubject the heart of the observable data service."

everything written just before that piece says that something like this should be instead: "no matter if you subscribe to `BehaviorSubject` before or after the value is `.next`ed to it, your subscribing code would work correctly, while with just simple `Subject`s, subscribing after the emission won't behave right."